# is there such a thing as an infinitely repeated digit in an integer

Tags: terminology

Is there such a thing as an infinitely repeated digit in an integer?

Analogous to how there are repeating or recurring decimals.

If there is what do you call them(if they indeed have a name)? If not why?

For example, I mean numbers like:

$...999999999, ...4444444412, ...11111111, etc.$

I tried looking up "infinitely repeated digit in an integer" and similar things on Google but I got nothing for whatever reason. Surely, I couldn't have been the first person to think about this, no?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Not in regular integers, but read about [p-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)

Comment: No such integers does not satisfy Archimedean property

Comment: @J.W.Tanner At this point, p-adic numbers are a bit over my head but I'm hoping to work towards them anyway. They seem interesting. P.S — Do you know the term for the type of numbers I just described?

Comment: @user12986714 This is a property of some system of numbers and therefore does not hold in others, right?

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about the ordinary decimal representation of integers, the answer is *no*. For example, your $...111111$ is an abbreviation for $\sum_{n\ge 0}10^n$, which is a divergent series and therefore does not represent any integer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, ok. Thanks that makes sense.

Comment: @Mymistake: You’re welcome.

Comment: Yes. Yet integers in this context, if referring to some "normal" real numbers, need to satisfy that property